# OrderBy and OrderbyDescending on multiple variables not giving expected results

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to sort a list. Each element in that list has var1, var2 and var3.

When I try the below code:

```
var orderedList = copiedList.OrderByDescending(c => c.var1).ThenBy(d => d.var2).ThenBy(e => e.var3).ToList();
```

I get var1 descending as I want, but I also get var2 descending as well instead of ascending.

I tried changing var2 to OrderByDescending as well try to reverse the effect but it didn't work.

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong and how to get var2 and var3 ascending while still getting var1 descending?

Comment: It works as expected when I test, can you provide example code that recreates the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually ordering incorrectly? var2 could naturally ascend when var1 is ordered in descending. Maybe posting your result set would help.

Comment: what are the types of var1, var2, and var3?

Comment: the type is double of all three

Comment: Example, (v1:0.5 v2:102 v3:1), (v1:0.5 v2:0 v3:1). 102 is larger than zero, why is it coming before zero if v1 is 0.5 in both cases?

Comment: Why the down votes? At least mention why in the comments. (Down voted because:)

Comment: Are you sure v1 is exactly 0.5? You are using doubles here. They could be slightly different because of rounding.

Comment: Yes I checked using breakpoints and looking at the stored value in the list elements. Other values (unrelated) in the elements show more decimal points.

Comment: Just wanted to check if that is normal or no, I'll check my code, just wanted to know what is the normal behavior, thanks. If it sounds weird then I'm probably doing something wrong, just wanted to confirm the understanding with more familiar folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a problem in some other part of your code, or with the type of collection you are using. This code yields the expected result:

```
class TestClass {
    public double var1 { get; set; }
    public double var2 { get; set; }
    public double var3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then using this class:

```
        List<TestClass> l = new List<TestClass>();
        l.Add(new TestClass() { var1 = 0.5, var2 = 102, var3 = 1 });
        l.Add(new TestClass() { var1 = 0.5, var2 = 0, var3 = 1 });
        List<TestClass> ordered = l.OrderByDescending(c => c.var1).ThenBy(d => d.var2).ThenBy(e => e.var3).ToList();
```

When I run this, the instance with var2 = 0 always appears first in the ordered list.

Comment: You mean var2 = 0 appears first?